# Download file from webservice

Tags: rest, file, api, download

I want to download file on clik of image. We have rest api which download the zip file when called. I am.able to get desired output when call that api from browser and rest console. However when I try to call it from ajax call it gives cross domain origine present method not allowed error.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you overcomplicated it. If you can test your API from your browser, I assume it's a simple HTTP GET call so you don't need fancy stuff like Ajax: just open the link, your browser know how to download a file.

Opening in the same window: location.href = 'http://my_server.com/my_api/downloadFile/54ef654zeze4'

Opening in a new window: parent.open('http://my_server.com/my_api/downloadFile/54ef654zeze4')

Comment: Thanks PCO. It worked. Don't know why I missed this approach. But I want to keep my service method as 'POST' instead of 'GET' as I have to pass few details in object. In that case it gives below error :

Comment: In addition to above the error is  :XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'X'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'X' is therefore not allowed access.